# Total variation norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let's consider total variation norm ρ( , ) on $(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)),$ where $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is a Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Is it true that for probabiblity measures $P$ and $Q$
$$ρ(P,Q):=\sup_{A∈\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)}|P(A)−Q(A)|=\sup_{I=I_1\times\dots\times I_n}|P(I)−Q(I)|?$$ Here $I_k=(a_k, b_k].$ If it is, why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is not true: see the answer of Robert to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125984/difference-between-two-measures)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the sake of clarity, let me adopt [the mentioned example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/126000/5887) precisely to your case. Consider the case $n = 2$ and let $P = \delta_{(0,0)} + \delta_{(1,1)}$ whereas $Q = \delta_{(0,1)}+\delta_{(1,0)}$. Then
$$
  \sup_{A,B\in\mathscr B(\Bbb R)}|P(A\times B) - Q(A\times B)| = 1
$$
but $|P(F) - Q(F)| = 2$ for $F = \{(0,0),(1,1)\}$.

Comment: Thanks! So are there any cases when it's true? What about the case when $P$ and $Q$ are the probability distributions of continuous stochatic variables? For example, normal distrubitons.

Comment: @dan think of approximating discrete distributions (for which we see it does not hold) with continuous ones